# How to increment a Vote field within a Django database of Voting System

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a system in which a person(Voter) will vote for a candidate against their 'Candidate Id', so for that Voter has to input the 'Emirates Id' (which is primary key of Voter) and 'Election Id' -which is primary key of the polling station - both these ID's will get validated to check if vote has been cast or not, but the problem really lies within my logic. here is my
**Views.py** :

```
def vote(request):
        can_id_obj = Candidate_Form.objects.get(pk=request.POST['Can_ID'])
        voterrecord = Election_Day(  #through this we will create an object of the class or our model 
            Can = can_id_obj,   #these are the fields in my 'Election Day' model
            emirates_id = Emirates_ID,
            election_id = Election_ID
        )
        voterrecord.Vote += 1   #we will call a field to manipulate it
        voterrecord.save()  #finally we can call save method on the object
        return render(request, 'Election_Day.html')
```

Everytime the vote gets polled, Instead of incrementing the same record for which the vote was previously cast, it will make a new record and then save the vote as 1, so basically i want it to increment the same record, if the vote has been polled for the same candidate.I hope you understand the explanation..

**Models.py** For reference

```
class Election_Day(models.Model):           
    Can = models.ForeignKey('Candidate_Form', on_delete=models.CASCADE)  #you refer the primary key to the whole class and it will automatically pick the id (primary key) of that class and make it a foreign key      #with that you can also access all the data stored in that table
    Elec = models.ForeignKey('Election_Info', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = 
    True) #you can make a foreign key null
    Vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    emirates_id = models.IntegerField()
    election_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: You need to be careful that you do not have race conditions where 2 requests increment `can_id_obj.Vote` at the same time, you would may lose a vote. It might be better to have a property on the candidate model that counts all related votes

Comment: it was a mistake can you check it again i have edited the save method line

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving `Candidate_Form` object. Just add `can_id_obj.save()` in the end like this.

```
def vote(request):
        can_id_obj = Candidate_Form.objects.get(pk=request.POST['Can_ID'])
        voterrecord = Election_Day(  #through this we will create an object of the class or our model 
            Can = can_id_obj,   #these are the fields in my 'Election Day' model
            emirates_id = Emirates_ID,
            election_id = Election_ID
        )
        can_id_obj.Vote += 1   #we will call a field to manipulate it
        can_id_obj.save()
        voterrecord.save()  #finally we can call save method on the object
        return render(request, 'Election_Day.html')
```

Comment: You are incrementing `Vote` attribute of `Candidate_Form` in `can_id_obj.Vote += 1`. You should save `can_id_obj` after this. Otherwise your changes will not be saved.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Candidate_Form' object has no attribute 'Vote' this is the error that it would invoke for your suggested solution

Comment: You are creating new object of Election_Day every time. It will always start with 0.

Comment: Yea, the same came into my mind aswell but, the problem is then i wont be able to validate if the vote exists or not

Comment: You should make a third model as well where you should be saving all vote casted for a candidate on an election. You can count those related objects to get vote count.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, thankyou man i didnt gave it a thought